# How to set i response status n Sprint cloud function for azurei

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I am new to Azure Functions, I would like to integrate Spring Cloud Function with Azure Function, I referred many articles but could not get any information regarding how to set HTTP response status and customize content produce from API using Spring cloud.

I am using the following Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <!--<version>5.0.10.RELEASE</version>-->
</dependency>
```

This is supposed to run on Azure Serverless platform.

1: Spring Function code:

```
public class AuthorizationFunction implements Function<String,ServicesOut> {

    @Autowired
    private someservice;


    @Override
    public DomainObject apply(String entitlement) {

    }
}
```

2: Spring Function Handler integrating Azure

```
public class EntitlementHandler extends AzureSpringBootRequestHandler<String, ServicesOut> {

    @FunctionName("functionname")
    public DomainObject execute(@HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.GET}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage request,
             ExecutionContext context) {

     // Depending on Function.apply value set httpresponse status and details
     // set 201 when success
     // set 401 when failure
     // set 500 for other failures
   }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can custom your response by return a `HttpResponseMessage`. For more details, you may refer to: [HttpRequestMessage and HttpResponseMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java#httprequestmessage-and-httpresponsemessage)

Here is my test:

### 1. Download the Azure function with spring function sample

```
git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/hello-spring-function-azure.git
```

### 2. Modify the class as following

**Class HelloHandler**

```
public class HelloHandler extends AzureSpringBootRequestHandler<HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>>, HttpResponseMessage> {

    @FunctionName("hello")
    public HttpResponseMessage execute(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>> request,
            ExecutionContext context) {

        context.getLogger().info("Greeting user name: " + request.getBody().get().getName());
        return handleRequest(request, context);
    }
}
```

**Class hello() function bean**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloFunction {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloFunction.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>>, HttpResponseMessage> hello() {
        return request -> request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(request.getBody().get().getName()).build();
    }
}
```

### 3. Result

As I chenged the function, so I removed all the test class. Because it did not match any more. If you need the test, you should chage the test logic.

Then I just ran the function in terminal with: `mvn clean package azure-functions:run`

And then I made a http request, and got the following response:

[image]

you can see that the response http status is "Accepted", which is correct as I set in the function.

Comment: Nice trick! But it doesn't work with latest Spring Cloud function & azure-functions-java-library 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I have pushed a sample project to [Github](https://github.com/MC-Sagar/Azure-Functions-Spring-Boot), Check it out.

This project has spring cloud functions in azure that can handle request and response effectively. I have added Firebase authentication to the sample API and also configured the database operations with JPA.